# What's the recommended reading order of reading order questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-order

Is there a recommended reading order of reading order questions?

Comment: I know I shouldn't promote this kind of behavior, but this seriously made my day.

Comment: This question totally deserves every down vote it gets. FWIW, I don't normally post questions like this, but this time I just couldn't help myself.

Comment: FWIW, I don't normally post comments like this, but this time I just couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[By votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order?sort=votes&pagesize=50).